# Javascript to Drag and Drop in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-events

Trying to do a simple drag and drop example in HTML5 - but when I drop the image into the div element I get the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

So I assume the error message means dragElement is null.  I don't understand why though, because I set it in the dragstart event to be the HTML of the img element.

Anyone know how to make this work?

```
var dragElement = null;

$('#x').bind('dragstart', function (e) {
    dragElement = this;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
});

$('#drop-box').bind('dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$('#drop-box').bind('drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    if (dragElement != this) {
        dragElement.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`dataTransfer` is part of the original event object, not the jQuery one. Use `e.originalEvent` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/KWut6/.

```
 e.originalEvent.dataTransfer ...
```

HTML

```
<image src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/" draggable="true" id="x">
<div id="drop-box">a</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var dragElement = null;

$('#x').bind('dragstart', function (e) {
    dragElement = this;
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
});

$('#drop-box').bind('dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$('#drop-box').bind('drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    if (dragElement != this) {
        dragElement.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Voted up because that was a problem, but not the problem causing the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" error.

The error is being caused by the line:

dragElement.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;

Comment: @Pete Oakey: The fiddle works fine for me without any errors. Are you experiencing something else?

Comment: I don't think so.  How come e.dataTransfer is OK on the dragstart event but not the drop event? By the way it is an image element that I am dragging and dropping - if that makes a difference!

Comment: It should not be available in either case. In the fiddle I've used `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer` everywhere.

Comment: Sorry - changed the id of my img element during my attempts to fix.  Changed it back and all works now :)