# event.dataTransfer.files is empty when ondrop is fired?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Okay, I have an element set up to receive a file-drop event, but when I look in `event.dataTransfer` it is blank. I haven't gotten around to learning the drag-n-drop HTML5 API just yet and am still a little foggy on it. I'm working on it at [my site](http://southshift.com/backstage/). If you wouldn't mind poking around my code and seeing what's going on, it would be highly appreciated. The entire `event` object is being logged.

Comment: see here [e.originalEvent.dataTransfer ...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189918/javascript-to-drag-and-drop-in-html5

Comment: I have same problem, please look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69165465/angular-drag-and-drop-empty-files-array-in-event If you have a solution .

Answer (score 214, accepted):

It's working fine, it's just a bug with the console.

```
function onDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: Note to others: You have to be CAREFUL.  This bug means that you will see an empty object in the console for ANY of the following: `console.log(JSON.stringify(event))`, `console.log(JSON.stringify(event.dataTransfer))`, `console.log(JSON.stringify(event.dataTransfer.files))`, and `console.log(JSON.stringify(event.dataTransfer.files[0]))`.  ONLY displaying a leaf node, such as `console.log(JSON.stringify(event.dataTransfer.files[0].name))` works.  I personally find this sickening, lost me hours - and why?  Who knows.  But this is a heads up for anyone else who runs into this problem.

Comment: 'Bug' from 2012 still being observed in 2019. Is there any known reported bug on this issue or more background in what causes this odd behavior?

Comment: Bug from 2020 still present in 2020. This is straight up unacceptable

Comment: 1 year after the Great Cataclysm of 2020. Even `event.dataTransfer.files.length` is 0 while `event.dataTransfer.items` has 2 file items

Comment: Still a bug in 2021 :(

Comment: ...a bug in _what_, specifically? Any particular browser, perhaps? All the browsers? The standard itself?

Comment: Can't imagine I wasted more than 2 hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Still a bug with latest version of Chrome...seems to be working fine with Firefox.

Comment: For anyone interested in why this gotcha happens I found the following report - 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1001117&q=%22fileList%22%20empty&can=1

LTS: event.dataTransfer and event.fileList are live objects that are only populated during the execution of the handler. Once they finished doing what they need to do the objects go back in to protected mode which is essentially an empty object that will always be length 0.

Comment: 2022 and still a bug.  Need to buy this man a coffee

Comment: 2023, thank you! There is no way I would ever figure this out.... How is this still a bug haha

Comment: There is [a Note on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/files): _The `files` property of `DataTransfer` objects can only be accessed from within the `drop` event. For all other events, the `files` property will be empty — because its underlying data store will be in a [protected mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#the-drag-data-store)._

Comment: When using the step debugger, `e.dataTransfer` is always null, even for a properly programmed drag and drop flow which works perfectly if the step debugger is not used. Guess it's the simplest to simply initiate your own Js object within the `dragstart` even handler, within an IIFE or so for private scoping, and then get that object during the `drop` event. That's how I do it, it works and you can also use the step debugger without any problem with this.

Comment: still a bug in 2024 ;)

Answer (score 6):

Also take a look at this bug/behavior: [HTML5 drop event doesn't work unless dragover is handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414154/)

Basically, you need to handle hover/drag and specify a dropEffect

Comment: What do you mean? I pointed to a link that explains that there's a weird behavior related to drag/drop where if you don't specify a dropEffect in the drag handler, the dataTransfer object won't have any information in the drop handler (at least sometimes - I saw this only on chrome on ubuntu, not macos). I also pointed out the gist of the content contained in the page I linked to. What more do you need?

Comment: Generally on SO, you want to put the code/solution directly in your answer. This prevents dead links in the future :)

Comment: Fair enough - might be worth a flag as duplicate though, really.

Comment: Right this worked for me. In the dragstart event, put below code:
`event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "all"`;
`event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move"`

Answer (score -1):

I found what I needed in:

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer
```

Comment: This question is not about JQuery

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solved my problem (used Jquery)