# event.dataTransfer.files vs. event.dataTransfer.items

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm playing with [drag-and-drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop) and there are two ways of gathering files from a `DragEvent.dataTransfer`, there is `readonly files: FileList` and `readonly items: DataTransferItemList`.

It seems that `items` is superset of `files`, gathering `File[]` from `items` is more complicated and also `items` are not supported in older IE, so `files` are easier to work with and has better support, yet the article on MDN uses `items` first and only when its not supported, switch to `files`.

My question is, if I need to gather only `File[]` collection from `DragEvent`, can I go with `dataTransfer.files` property or does `dataTransfer.items` has some benefits, which is worth?

## Self Answer:

In modern browser (chrome), the `files` collection is empty. The dragged file is reachable only through `items`, so you cannot rely solely on `files`.

Comment: and dataTransfer.items only supported by Chrome. according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=drag), so use the `.items` property for chrome and `.files` elsewhere

Comment: But you may check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573710/event-datatransfer-files-is-empty-when-ondrop-is-fired) for the empty files property of chrome

Comment: It seems `files` collection is not empty, at least for Version 63.0.3239.132 (Developer Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Firefox 100 has dataTransfer.items support

Answer (score 11):

The major difference between `dataTransfer.items` and `dataTransfer.files` is that `dataTransfer.items` also contains the subdirectories.

This is important if you want to Drag&Drop subdirectories (e.g. to upload the entire directory tree, with all the files in it)

Below is an example how that would be accomplished:

```
function DragAndDrop_Handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {        
        var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();  //Might be renamed to GetAsEntry() in 2020
        if (item) {
            GetFileTree(item);
        }
    }
}


function GetFileTree(item, path) {
    path = path || "";
    if (item.isFile) {

        item.file(function(file) {
            console.log(file);
        });
        
    } else if (item.isDirectory) {

        console.log(item.fullPath);  //console.log(item.name)

        // Get folder contents  
        var dirReader = item.createReader();
        dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
            for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                GetFileTree(entries[i], path + item.name + "/");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note: In the Chrome browser the `dataTransfer.files` is deprecated and returns an empty collection.

Comment: It seems getting the `path` has also been deprecated. I an trying to get the path and the filename with no luck in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't find any proper explanation of the difference between that two APIs. But after my experiments on that API, I found out that the `dataTransfer.items` is much newer and is defined to provide not just file drops but also drag and drop functionality(i.e. when you want to drag some item from your page to another part of your page). And since I don't care about old IEs I'm only using `dataTransfer.items`.

Comment: If you drag an image from your desktop, it will only appear in files, not items, in chrome. So you do need to check both. But there are occasions when a drag+dropped file will appear in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When you drop items the browser (at least modern Chrome and Safari) creates an instance of the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) for each of them (regardless of whether it is a file or a directory) and puts it in the `dataTransfer.files` (which is an instance of [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)). And there is no way to get a list of files from that directory (as well as nested subdirectories and files). It's possible only via `dataTransfer.items`. That's the major difference.